# ROS2 Colcon debug symbols for use with DDD

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to get Colcon to build ROS2 binaries with debug symbols so that I can run nodes with something like DDD?

I'm able to run using DDD with the following command:

```
ros2 run --prefix 'ddd' ros1_bridge dynamic_bridge
```

But without debug symbols, I can't use feature like breakpoints or stepping through the source code.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320252/ros2-colcon-debug-symbols-for-use-with-ddd/) by [mlanting](https://answers.ros.org/users/2091/mlanting/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2019-04-03

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to do this with:

```
colcon build <other_args> --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo
```

instead of using `RelWithDebInfo` you could use `Debug` if you really don't want any optimisation.

Assuming the project you're building is a CMake project of course (which the bridge is).

---

Edit:

> Is there a way to get Colcon to build ROS2 binaries

pedantic perhaps, but colcon doesn't build anything. It drives other tools. So in this case we're asking colcon to pass on some arguments for CMake, which in the end will cause it to generate build scripts that will actually compile things with debug flags enabled.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mlanting](https://answers.ros.org/users/2091/mlanting/) on 2019-04-03**:
Exactly what I needed, thanks!